# What does serving the web app manifest with "HTTP header "Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json" exactly mean?

Tags: html

I am a noob in web apps dev and I am confused as to where to declare the said "Content-Type".  Should it be on the manifest or should it be on the app source code? I am using dropbox public folder as my server which I am not sure too if that's a problem.

i have created 2 files: my html source code for the app AND the manifest.

The top part of my manifest is something like this:

> {
>
> "name":"my app name",
>
> "description": "my app desc",
>
> "launch_path": "http://dl.dropbox.com/x/xxxxx/xxxxxx.html"
>
> "icons": {
>
> "128": "http://dl.dropbox.com/x/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx_128px.png"
>
> }

It is saved as "myManifest.webapp".

And, my source code top part is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html  lang="en">  
   <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>My App Name</title>
</head>
```

I tried to validate my manifest via Firefox Marketplace but I keep failing it with 3 errors:

-JSON Parse Error;

-Manifests must be served with the HTTP header "Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json".

-The manifest's encoding does not match the charset provided in the HTTP Content-Type.

Any help to get me through this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's talking about the [*HTTP `Content-Type` header*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers). That's a header send as part of the HTTP protocol, *before the actual file data*. It's not anything in the file itself, it's a setting set by the web server which is serving the file via the HTTP protocol.

This header tells the browser unambiguously what kind of file it's dealing with, because the URL does not necessarily have anything to do with the file being served from it.

I don't know if you have any influence over this header when just using Dropbox.

Comment: " It's not anything in the file itself" Thank you thank you so much. I've searched whole day and didn't find that answer! I love you stackoverflow!

Comment: [I am facing a similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864490/validation-error-while-submitting-app-to-firefox-marketplace). I did not understand what was changed by OP to resolve this issue. @deceze

Comment: @whiteglider ^ I did not get how you fixed this issue.