# Validation error while submitting app to Firefox Marketplace

Tags: json, github, content-type, firefox-os

I was validating my manifest on [this page](https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/submit/) with this manifest URL of my app hosted on GitHub:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/my_username/my_application/master/manifest.webapp
```

This is the error I got:

> Manifests must be served with the HTTP header "`Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json`". See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Apps/Manifest#Serving_manifests for more information.

So I checked that link mentioned in the error and it says:

> If you serve your manifest file from GitHub Pages, GitHub will serve it with the Content-Type header of `application/x-web-app-manifest+json`.

Assuming that I need to create a [GitHub page](https://pages.github.com/) for my app, I created it and passed on that link to validate. Then I got 2 errors:

> 1. JSON Parse Error
> 2. Manifests must be served with the HTTP header "`Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json`". See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Apps/Manifest#Serving_manifests for more information.

My JSON is valid, I had it checked on jsLint. Also, I am assuming that the GitHub page is passing on the required header when I am giving the respective URL. Still it's failing.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not serving this manifest over GitHub pages, but as 'Raw' content. All content on raw.githubusercontent.com is served as text/plain.

Use [real Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) to make this work.

Comment: I had tried it with my Github page as well. The URL looks like `http://my_username.github.io/my_application/`. Still I got the same 2 errors mentioned in the question.

Comment: I also tried submitting a packaged app, but there was an error `    Error extracting manifest from zip file.` I cant think of any reason why this is happening. Everything looks ok to me on my side.

Comment: Did you zip the *contents* of the folder or the folder itself? The manifest should be in the root of your zip file.

Comment: Ah, I had actually zipped the folder. Now it works after zipping the contents of the folder. :) But I am wondering how to get it working through GitHub.